# OCaml without Core useless or not?

Tags: ocaml

Some time ago I started learning OCaml for improving my code skils. And now I wonder, is it worth to try use OCaml without Core, or it useful only with third party libs?

Comment: You do realize there are other third party libs than Core ? This question is a bit weird, most ocaml programmers don't use core ...

Comment: Yes I realize that. But Batteries and Containers looks more like additional libraries. Meanwhile Core looks like full replacement for standard ocaml library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not useless. Moreover, Core is a library with a very high entrance barrier. So I would personally suggest to learn OCaml without the Core library. And then switch to it, as soon as you start to use OCaml for real life coding.

Answer (score 0):

You may discover that ocaml has a [standard library](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/tree/trunk/stdlib).

Does Core support windows?

Comment: `core_kernel` supports windows.